# How can I request the vibrate permission?

Tags: android, android-vibration

How can I request the vibrate permission in my Android application?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Here is the link to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#VIBRATE)

Add this to your manifest, as a direct child of the `manifest` element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

This is how you let the phone Vibrate thru code:

```
// Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

// Vibrate for 300 milliseconds
v.vibrate(300);
```

For a more creative pattern try the star wars theme =D

```
v.vibrate(new long[]{0, 500, 110, 500, 110, 450, 110, 200, 110, 170, 40, 450, 110, 200, 110, 170, 40, 500}, -1);
```

Comment: hahaha, you wrote "vibrator" :'D Seriously, thanks for this answer! :)

Comment: To be really clear... add it within your <manifest ...> tag! Do not add it to any other tag!

Comment: If you can, update your answer with this: ```val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE) vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect)```. This is for Android O and newer versions.

Answer (score 29):

Add the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

More info on AndroidManifest permissions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions)

More info on list of permission [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: I have being looking for the permissions list for a while thanks